# Executing multiple MySQL inserts at once in Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a string that is basically a concatenation of multiple insert statements such as

```
sql = INSERT INTO test (a,b,c) VALUES ("test","test",1);INSERT INTO test (a,b,c) VALUES ("2nd test","2nd test",6);
```

When I run this in SQL as a query, it works fine and inserts both statements.

However, when I run it in python using the following:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = INSERT INTO test (a,b,c) VALUES ("test","test",1);INSERT INTO test (a,b,c) VALUES ("2nd test","2nd test",6);
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

I get this error:

```
ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

Whats the best way to resolve this and execute multiple statements in one go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is about the fact that `cursor.execute` can handle only one sql per run. you either want to loop it:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO test (a,b,c) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
for values in [("test","test",1), ("2nd test","2nd test",6)]
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

or execute at once:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO test (a,b,c) VALUES ("test","test",1),("2nd test","2nd test",6)'
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. For a variety of reasons needed them to go in all at once so the second method worked.