# How do I rectify the error in mysql-connector where I try to add multiple records at the same time into a MySQL Database?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to add multiple records into a database using mysql-connector-python. I was able to add one record initially but for multiple records, this error has been persistent.

```
class DataBase:
def __init__(self):
    try:
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='xx.xxx.xx.xx',
                                                 database='XXX',
                                                 user='XXXX',
                                                 password='xxxx')
        
    except Error as error:
        print("Failed to connect: {}".format(error))
        

def store_into_table(self, df):
        
        mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO data ('data_id', 'a', 'b', 'c') VALUES ('%S','%S', '%S', '%S') """
        records_to_insert = df
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(mySql_insert_query, records_to_insert)
        self.connection.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, " Records inserted successfully into data table")
```

The variable that I am passing to an instance of DataBase is:

```
data = [('101', 'name_1', '3', 'sample'), ('102', 'name_2', '5', 'sample_1')]
```

Exception being thrown:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/dev/anaconda3/envs/sql/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 317, in _batch_insert
    "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")

ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-123-44fdf194cd10>", line 1, in <module>
    db.store_into_table(data)

  File "/Users/dev/Detector/database.py", line 30, in store_into_table
    cursor.executemany(mySql_insert_query, records_to_insert)

  File "/Users/dev/anaconda3/envs/sql/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 350, in executemany
    stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)

  File "/Users/dev/anaconda3/envs/sql/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 329, in _batch_insert
    "Failed executing the operation; %s" % err)

InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Any clues as to why this isn't working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing multiple MySQL inserts at once in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104519/executing-multiple-mysql-inserts-at-once-in-python)

Comment: I placed quotes for the %s part. Minor issue which I overlooked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO data (data_id, a, b, c) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) """
```

Comment: I am going to call you saviour. Thank you! It worked.